# What is the algorithmic speed up for Counting Perfect Matchings in Dense Bipartite Graphs (equivalent to Permanent of Dense 0/1 Matrices)?

Tags: ds.algorithms

The Idea is this:

The Decision problems Max Cut for graphs is APX-Hard and therefore does not have a PTAS.

However Dense versions of Max Cut do have a PTAS!

This suggest that Counting Perfect Matchings for Dense Bipartite Graphs could have some sort of speed up.

Does such a speedup exists in the complexity literature?

Further to the above, I am aware of the expectional work done on NonNegative Matrices. However I was really thinking about General matrices and expecting exponential algorithms. Of course #P is by standard complexity theory intractable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

*Jerrum, Mark; Sinclair, Alistair; Vigoda, Eric.*, [**A polynomial-time approximation algorithm for the permanent of a matrix with nonnegative entries**](https://doi.org/10.1145/1008731.1008738), J. ACM 51, No. 4, 671–697 (2004). [ZBL1204.65044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1204.65044).

?

If you are looking for exact algorithms, the only speedup I'm aware of is

*Bax, E.; Franklin, J.*, [**A permanent algorithm with $\exp[\Omega(n^{1/3}/2\ln n)]$ expected speedup for 0-1 matrices**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00453-001-0072-0), Algorithmica 32, No. 1, 157–162 (2002). [ZBL0995.68190](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0995.68190).

Which also can be used to show you can do $c^n$ time for $c<2$ for sparse 0/1 matrices or the UP-hard mod 3 permanent.